# Return struct as datatype from method in c++ class

Tags: c++, arduino

Got a simple class with a private array and some methods to read data from that array

```
class PinUtils {
  private:
    int pinMatrix[3][3] = {
      {2, LOW, OUTPUT },
      {3, LOW, OUTPUT },
      {4, LOW, OUTPUT }
    };

  public:

    struct PinSetting {
      int pinNumber;
      uint8_t state;    
      int pinType;
    };

    int pinLength(){
      return sizeof(pinMatrix)/sizeof(pinMatrix[0]);
    }

    PinSetting getPinSetting(int index){
      PinSetting pin;
      pin.pinNumber = pinMatrix[index][0];
      pin.state = pinMatrix[index][1];
      pin.pinType = pinMatrix[index][2];

      return pin;
    }    
};
```

I keep getting errors like `error: 'PinSetting' does not name a type`, the struct inside the class seem to generate this when I create the getPinSetting method.

Example call

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  PinUtils pin;

  for(int i = 0; i < pin.pinLength(); i++){
    PinUtils::PinSetting pinSetting = pin.getPinSetting(i);

    pinMode(pinSetting.pinNumber, pinSetting.pinType);
    digitalWrite(pinSetting.pinNumber, pinSetting.state);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: @MarkRansom the init of the `PinSetting pin;`

Comment: You didn't forget to `#include` the file that declares the class, did you?

Comment: @MarkRansom No, currently all is in the same file

Comment: Hacked out this: http://ideone.com/jPhygd and unable to reproduce. Can we get an MCVE?

Comment: Then is `setup` *below* the code for `PinUtils`?

Comment: With an empty loop() and replacing use of pinMatrix with hardcoded consts on arduino 1.04, builds fine for me.

Comment: need to declare like `typesdef struct PinSetting`, or cast to `(struct)` each use.